# generating many sheets after each Macro run

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote a VBA code  in Excel (which is big and  works fine). After each run couple of empty sheets are generated, see [image: Pic]! 
I do not even for which key word I should search too be able to find a solution. Dose some one know why these are generated and how can I get rid of them. I would be grateful even if there is key word suggestion where I can search for it in google.

Comment: Could be a few things. Could be `Sheets.Add` or you could be copying sheets, or moving them.

Comment: It seems like your code is adding a sheet somewhere, but it's hard to tell you where the exact problem is without a look at your code.

The code you would look for should be something like Worksheets.Add or Sheets.Add.

Comment: I see thanks anyway I go again through my code but it is really bigger than I can put it here

Comment: There's a part of your code that's going to have the worksheets get added, find those parts and add here.  Without your code it's really hard for us to give specific help.

Comment: Guys Thanks a lot I found the place which generate it, and I know why! I can just flag up your hints